# Can towns be founded during a game in OpenTTD?

Tags: openttd

I just started a small map (64x64), and there is only one town. It's 1890 and I don't know if I'll have to play the entire game with just one town.

Can another town appear during the game? Can I found a new town?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an advanced setting that allows you to found towns during the game.  It can be configured during a game and turning it on will allow you to found a new town.

More information can be found at: http://wiki.openttd.org/Advanced_Settings/Economy#Founding_towns_in_game

Once it is turned on, founding a new town is available from the Town List under the 'town' menu.  (see comment below)

Comment: Yeah It works! BUT it appears under the Town List in the town menu. Thanks!

Comment: cool, updated answer to reflect that fact - glad I could be of assistance, anyway :)

Comment: wow, 50 million to create...I'll have to wait!